# How to remove unneccesary View behind DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android-dialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I implemented this example from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwe1abDO2Ag). There in that example you can see he is running with a dialog style like this [old style for DatePickerDialog without border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7i8G.png)

When I use this, I can clearly see an additional view behind that dialog: [date picker dialog with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPny9.jpg)

**How can I remove that additional view behind MY date picker dialog?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```